# Using a process to execute utl_recomp on client server

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlplus

What I am trying to do is create a process that opens sqlplus, connects to a remote server and executes a recompile of the database.

```
string arg =                  
         "\"conn " + myConnect + " as sysdba \""+
         "\"begin UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL('" + mySchema + "'); end;\"";

Process pro = new Process()  
pro.StartInfo.FileName = "sqlplus.exe";
pro.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
pro.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["ORACLE_HOME"] = Srvr.OH;
pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
pro.Start();
pro.WaitForExit();
```

The process runs but my objects are still invalid.  I have remotely connected and ran this sql statement successfully as a sysdba from the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you intend to use escape sequences and one of your strings doesn't.  Get rid of the @ prefix.

Comment: @ prefix was being used as a string literal previously.  I edit it here and have been removed from my source code, but still the same issue.  Thanks for pointing that out Zer0.

Comment: Which objects are invalid and why?  Take a look at `select * from dba_errors where owner = 'MYSCHEMA';`.  It may be that recompiling alone won't fix the problem.

Comment: Jon Heller I ran your sql statement and got no rows returned.  When I run `select object_type, object_name, status from dba_objects where status='INVALID';` I get like 400+ invalid objects returned.  I'd like to mention that this process is run after an upgrade so when I do recompile with `recomp_serial` and `recomp_parallel` I end up with no rows returned on my invalid sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string mySqlPath = path + ".sql";
string mysql = "begin UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL('" + mySchema + "'); end;";

string arg =   
         " /c echo / | " + pathway +"sqlplus.exe"               
         " -silent " + myConnect + " as sysdba" +
         "@" + mysql;

StreamWriter strWr = new StreamWriter(mySqlPath);
strWr.WriteLine(mysql);
strWr.WriteLine("/");
strWr.Close();

Process pro = new Process()  
pro.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
pro.StartInfo.Arguments = arg;
pro.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["ORACLE_HOME"] = Srvr.OH;
pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
pro.Start();
pro.WaitForExit();
```

This works perfectly for recompiling remotely! Was a long haul trying to figure it out but had to add a lot more code as you can see. The "cmd" in filename required that I shutdown the database, mount the database, alter database archive log, alter database flashback on, alter database open, then exit.  The recompile completed successfully, as well as, my validation process, which came back with 0 rows selected for 'INVALID'.